# How do you select from multiple tables when a where statment is involved.

Tags: php, mysql

I need to pull info from multiple tables but I don't want the entries where archive is equal to zero. I can achieve this fine when I do it from one table but it doesn't work when I try it from multiple ones.. Please help!

```
if ($_SESSION['user_type']== 1){
$sql="SELECT * FROM orlando,indy WHERE archive='0'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}
else
die('You do not have access');
```

Comment: Can you post the table structures? They'll be needed to answer this question.

Comment: The table structures have 30 different fields in them so its a bit much.. But both are exactly the same.

Comment: Good enough. In that case, the answer from @compid should do nicely. Since there are five tables use `select * from orlando where archive <> '0' union all select * from indy where archive <> 0 union all select * from boston where archive <> 0 union all...` you get the idea :) The MrVimes answer isn't good here (though it's appropriate for other cases) because it will match all rows from all of the tables to each other. In other words, if each table has 100 rows your result will have as many as 10^5 (10 billion) rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if `UNION ALL` fits what you are trying to do...

```
SELECT * FROM orlando WHERE archive='0' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM indy WHERE archive='0'
```

Comment: This worked but when I tried doing more then 2 tables there was an error. I guess I should have mentioned that there is 5 tables.. but I was trying to simplify it.

Comment: No problem! Yes, it gets clumsy when you have to repeat the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from orlando,indy where orlando.archive <> '0' and indy.archive <> '0'
```